# Border around tables within tables html email

Tags: html, html-email

I'm trying fiddling around with html emails and I'm trying to put a border around the outside of all the tables and this was the result:

[end result](https://i.imgur.com/x7KWbkR.png)

Here is the code:
[link to code](https://www.reddit.com/r/html5/comments/5z1i1i/border_problems/)

Thank you in advance and I apologize if this has too many links.

Comment: post your code as text here

Comment: I tried...but it said it wouldn't post because I only allowed two links? In my code? I had three.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to place one table inside the second, add padding to the outer table td, give it a bgcolor. Next add bgcolor to the inside table and you are good to go.

Below is the code, give it a try.

```html
<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-bottom:1px;padding-left:1px;" bgcolor="#cccccc">
 
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 
   
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Cheers